# Arbitrary precision FFT and IFFT

Tags: fft, numerical-algorithms

For evaluating the performance of algorithms that use double-precision floating point numbers, or to pre-calculate double-precision floating point data to the best precision, it would sometimes be useful to evaluate the **discrete Fourier transform** (DFT) and the **inverse discrete Fourier transform** (IDFT) at arbitrary precision greater than the precision of double-precision floating point numbers. Python's [mpmath library](http://mpmath.org/) would be a well-suited framework on which to build an arbitrary precision **fast Fourier transform** (FFT) and **inverse fast Fourier transform** (IFFT) library.

Is there such an implementation available? If no, then this is a request to develop and present a reference implementation.

(Hint:  [**chirp-z transform**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/77156/230294) might be the easiest way to deal with any DFT length that is not a power of two.)

Comment: Would this be what you're looking after: https://www.advanpix.com/2012/04/11/arbitrary-precision-fast-fourier-transform/

Comment: @JuhaP looks good but it's not free unfortunately.

Comment: Bumped to this Python project: https://github.com/dbstein/apfft ... maybe something to start from ...

Comment: FFT code is readily available and only contains multiply and adds. Why don't you just combine that with a free arbitrary precision package? Only tricky point is probably pre-computing the twiddle factors since that requires transcendent functions . It can be done recursively with complex multiply (but precision may suffer). or using a sufficiently long Taylor expansion $\sum x^n/n!$

Comment: @JuhaP looks to be for powers of 2 only

Comment: @Hilmar "mpmath provides extensive support for transcendental functions" so those are not a problem. To decipher someone's platform-native floating-point FFT implementation in C and to convert it to Python or to modify it and combine it with some other multi-precision library than mpmath sounds more difficult than starting from scratch, for example by combining chirp-z transform with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm#Pseudocode

Comment: Stupid question from my side: do you know the scales of the input values beforehand, or do really all computations need to be done using arbitrary precision math? By the way, how large are the transforms you're interested in, both in size of the vectors, and input value bit depths, in orders of magnitude?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It may be useful to have this available as a general tool, so I wouldn't want to limit the input precision or the size based on any task at hand.

Comment: Well, the problem that I see is that arbitrary precision at every single multiplication and addition requires quite a bit of computational overhead, so if memory is not a relevant constraint, just converting all input to the same precision and then doing the DFT naively (which is worse by $(\log N)/N$ than an FFT) without special-casing every single arithmetic operation would still be more efficient, as long as SIMD and lack of branching make uniform operations $N/\log N$ times faster than the average arbitrary precision op.

Comment: @MarcusMüller For the same level of maximum absolute or RMS error, a direct evaluation of DFT needs better floating-point precision than does FFT, be it arbitrary precision or the precision of a native floating-point type. So I don't see anything in favor of direct evaluation, except for the simplicity of programming it. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Accuracy

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo waitasecond, if you're doing arbitrary precision, why would you have *any* numerical error, either way? But the point is that you were looking for an arbitrary precision FFT, whereas I'm proposing that you need a fixed-precision way of calculating the DFT, and we know how to do fixed-point DFTs (and FFT), and due to linearity of the DFT, you can stitch together the results of "the DFT of the upper 32 bit of the inputs", "the next 32 bit of the input"... "the least 32 bit of the input", for example.

Comment: @MarcusMüller using an arbitrary precision library such as mpmath, the precision can be set by the user, for example in mpmath that setting is stored in the variable `mp.prec` as the number of bits of precision. When a result of a calculation gets rounded to that precision, or is only calculated to approximately that precision, there will be numerical error.